# Ansible child group variables not overriding parent group variables

Tags: ansible, vagrant

Based on Ansible documentation about [Assigning a variable to many machines: group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-one-machine-host-variables), a child group variable is supposed to override a parent group variable. In the structure below, variables defined on the child group are not being set.

**main.yml**

```
- name: apply common configuration to server
  hosts: all
  user: deployer
  roles:
    - common
```

**group_vars/all.yml**

```
deploy_ssl: false
app_dir: /home/{{ deploy_user }}/{{ app_name }}
venv_dir: "/home/{{ deploy_user }}/venvs/{{ app_name }}"
venv_python: "{{ venv_dir }}/bin/python"
```

**hosts.yml**

```
all:
  children:
    vagrant:
      hosts:
        local:
          ansible_host: 192.168.33.10
          ansible_user: vagrant
          ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/workspace/myuser/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
      vars:
        deploy_ssl: false
        app_dir: /vagrant
        venv_dir: /vagrant/venv
        venv_python: /vagrant/venv/bin/python
```

The command for `ansible-playbook` is:

```
ansible-playbook main.yml -i hosts.yml --limit vagrant --tags wsgi
```

Checking the results on the VM, the variables defined in the `hosts.yml` file for vagrant using the `vars` keyword are not overriding the values from the `group_vars/all.yml` file.

I can create a file specifically for the `vagrant` group as `group_vars/vagrant.yml', and that indeed works as expected. What I don't understand is why the`vars`keyword inside the`hosts.yml` file has no effect.

Comment: 1) Is ￼deploy.yml and main.yml the same? 2) What is the task selected by "--tags wsgi" ? ... See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo! I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Q: "`The variables defined in the hosts.yml file for vagrant using the vars keyword are not overriding the values from the group_vars/all.yml file`"

A: Because "`inventory group_vars/all`" has higher precedence compared to "`inventory file or script group vars`". See [Ansible variable precedence](https://gist.github.com/ekreutz/301c3d38a50abbaad38e638d8361a89e#ansible-variable-precedence).

Q: "`What would be the command to run ansible only for the vagrant hosts without using --limit?`"

A: Set *vagrant* hosts pattern in the playbook

```
- name: apply common configuration to server
  hosts: vagrant
```

and run the playbook

```
ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i hosts.yml --tags wsgi
```

You're right. It's the same as running

```
ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i hosts.yml --tags wsgi --limit vagrant
```

with

```
- name: apply common configuration to server
  hosts: all
```

To override the variables in group_vars/all.yml it is necessary to put the variables into the file  group_vars/vagrant.yml

```
    $ cat group_vars/vagrant.yml
    deploy_ssl: false
    app_dir: /vagrant
    venv_dir: /vagrant/venv
    venv_python: /vagrant/venv/bin/python
```

Comment: Reading [Best practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#what-this-organization-enables-examples) the purpose of `--limit` is the opposite of excluding, it actually only includes the hosts within a certain group.

Comment: In your link, I see it says exclusion, but [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html?highlight=limit#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-l) it says further limiting selected hosts. This sounds contradictory to me! What am I missing?

Comment: So, what would be the command to run ansible only for the vagrant hosts without using `--limit`?